# Iterating through a JSON file and checking for matches

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a local json file, iterate through every object in it and importing all the information of the of the object whose "Country" matches a pre-determined var name.

My JSON file (./olympics.json) looks something like this:

```
{
"list": [
{
  "Country": "United States",
  "IOC": "USA",
  "Summer_Gold": "1,070",
  "Summer_Silver": 841,
  "Summer_Bronze": 745,
  "Summer_Total": "2,656",
  "Winter_Gold": 105,
  "Winter_Silver": 113,
  "Winter_Bronze": 89,
  "Winter_Total": 307,
  "Total_Gold": "1,175",
  "Total_Silver": 954,
  "Total_Bronze": 834,
  "Total_Total": "2,963"
},
...
]}
```

And what I tried to do to was:

```js
$(".ModArea").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('title');
  $("#country_name").html(name);
  var json = require('./olympics.json');
  var array = json.list;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var check = array[i];
    if (check["Country"] === name) {
      var ioc = check["IOC"];
    }
  }
  $("#IOC").html(ioc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="europe_img" src="https://mapswire.com/download/europe/europe-political-map-miller.jpg" usemap="#europe" alt="Europe">
<map name="europe">
        <area class="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374"
              shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
              
        <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="country_name"></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="IOC">IOC: </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </map>
```

The part about editing the modal's header works perfectly, while the part about the IOC doesn't work at all, could someone help me understand why?

Comment: What is the require() keyword? Are you using requireJS or something else?

Comment: @n00b yes, I'm using requireJS

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're defining the ioc variable inside an if statement. It has no value outside that block, and this is why your code is behaving the way it is.

Also, I would suggest you use the find() method of Array. You can modify your code to look like this:

```
$(".ModArea").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('title');
  $("#country_name").html(name);
  var json = require('./olympics.json');

  $("#IOC").html(json.list.find(element => element.Country === name));
});
```

It is shorter, it uses a more recent API and it has better performance, due to the optimizations that find() offers.

Comment: I understand how the code should work, but when I tried implementing it the body still remained "IOC: "

Comment: This could only happen if json.list.find(element => element.Country === name) returns no elements. Can you try to log the return value of that code, for double checking it?

Comment: using F12 tells me that the problem is that require is not definted, but I installed requireJS via pip on my end, so how could I solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can install js dependencies through pip. 
Instead use <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>

Comment: @NiceBooks using that code the error changed to "Module name 'olympics.json' has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])". so I tried to implement the solution written here (https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) with the code from Gregorio but I'm having some problems with the element.Country part, as it now tells me "script error for ./olympics.json"

Comment: this is how I tried to update the code:

require(['../olympics.json'], function (json) {

    $("#IOC").html(json.list.find(element => element.Country === name));

});

Comment: It seems to be a different problem related to requirejs itself. Kindly post a new question.

Comment: @NiceBooks did it